# How to loop through chrome.tabs.query array? Getting Unexpected property: 'active'

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

**I'm getting this error:** I'm making an extension that reloads all opened pages when clicked. However, I'm getting this error below, hopefully some of you have an idea what kind of mess I'm up to :(

```
Error handling response: TypeError: Error in invocation of tabs.reload(optional integer tabId, optional object reloadProperties, optional function callback): Error at parameter 'reloadProperties': Unexpected property: 'active'.
    at chrome-extension://gdhcdepfjofmkahiggacnpphkadkjmdo/background.js:11:25
```

**Code:**

```
//When icon clicked
    chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
        //make array
        var allTabs = [];
        //empty {} means select all tabs in browser
        chrome.tabs.query({}, function(tab) {
            //loop that shit
            for (i = 0; i < tab.length; i = i + 1) {
                //push that shit
                allTabs.push(tab[i]);
                chrome.tabs.reload(tab[i]);
            }
            //log that shit
            console.log(allTabs);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `tab` contains an array of [Tab](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#type-Tab) objects. And [reload()](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-reload) method requires an integer `tabId` and not an object.

So to achieve the expected result, call the `reload` method as follows:
`chrome.tabs.reload(tab[i].id);`

Comment: Jesus...I'm blind, ofc...thanks so much! ;) Giving you some points in 5 mins!

Comment: There ya go, have a nice day ;)